# Copy/Paste in WebView

Tags: android

What I trying is to insert keystrokes into a WebView which will load a URL. In the webpage there will be data field in which i want to copy/paste some data there.

If I long press on the field can choose the copy all or paste but I want to automate this, so does when user clicks on a button for example it will insert some data into the data field or copy out some data.

I tried using KeyEvent API but so far no improvement. How do I go about doing this?

Regards, 
Perumal

Comment: Can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583771/enabling-copy-and-paste-in-webview-android

Comment: share the code what ur using