# Enabling copy and paste in webview android

Tags: android

Is it possible to select the text from a webview then to copy and paste.
Is there any special method to do this??Please help me..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#emulateShiftHeld%28%29

Comment: Are you talking about allowing users to copy and paste in fields of a form being viewed in a Webview that you are displaying in your application?

Comment: @Stan not html form. normal texts in the html pages.

Comment: I just tested on an embedded webview on gingerbread 2.3.7 and jelly bean 4.1.1. Nothing special in the code to allow copy/paste, but I was able to copy some text (from html body) and paste into another app or an html form in the same embedded webview.  The copy/paste in webkit is a bit less smooth than in native android views, but after a couple long press attempts, it was possible.  Maybe it has something to do with the html you are displaying in the WebView?

Comment: I need this feature on Android 2.1 devices. Sorry i forgot to add this on title.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you...

```
public void selectAndCopyText() {
     try {
         Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("emulateShiftHeld", Boolean.TYPE); 
            m.invoke(BookView.mWebView, false); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // fallback
            KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,
                 KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
            shiftPressEvent.dispatch(this);
        }

}
```

override the touch events

```
private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view)
    {
        try
        {
            KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
            shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);
            Toast.makeText(this, "select_text_now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [site](http://android-ed.blogspot.com/2012/10/copy-text-in-webview-in-android-23-and.html?m=1) of someone's blog says " Copy functionality in a WebView is available by default in Android 3.0 and above", and may be this information may be help, [Android: how to select texts from webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview)